# Bootstrap menu set caret toggle on mobile version

Tags: mobile, menu, toggle, caret

I'm new to Bootstrap and trying to create a menu with submenus which should work both in desktop and mobile versions.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" href="parentlink"><b class="caret"></b></a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="link1"></a></li>
       <li><a href="link2"></a></li>
       <li><a href="link3"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </ul>
</div>
```

and css for caret

```
.navbar .nav li.dropdown.open>.dropdown-toggle .caret {
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav .caret {
  display:none;
 }

 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
  }
}
```

Parent links can expand and show submenus on click. What I want to do is to make a parent link clickable on mobile version and open/close it by clicking on a caret. Any ideas?